# Usage of mobile/client-side databases in react apps with redux

Tags: javascript, database, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have been looking for answers or comparisons that what good having a mobile/client-side database would do for my application.

Lets assume, I have a react/react-native app with redux. Now I have this redux state to store my data/values etc locally and for my offline first apps too. Where does the mobile databases such as realm come in use in this scenario and how so?

I understand that if I really don't see any point of using those then I probably do not need it but I would like to know if they would provide me with any advantages that I would not get with redux.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main advantage that some DB is provide you is `persist` any information into your application, so remember `redux` is a state manager, so as a `state` word says, is just a state that will be away if your restart your application, so if you use a database you can persist any data that you need any time your app is starting, `redux` will working fine when the data is loaded in memory, but once your memory is flushed your state will disappear.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Yes you are right. That is why we combine redux-persist library to rehydrate the state or if we use redux-offline which also takes care of persisting. In this case can we say that redux with persisting/rehydration and having mobile databases would be the same idea? if i flush the applications memory wouldn't it also flush the databases data?